# Is this the cheapest and time-saving combination to get from LAX to Downtown LA?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, los-angeles

[This site](http://www.la-electric-travel.com/LAX-via-Metro-Rail.html) suggests a cheap way of getting from LAX to downtown LA via LA's Metro Rail. Could someone please verify whether it is still a valid itinerary, and whether it is possibly the best time+price combination to get from LAX to downtown LA?

Also, if this itinerary is still valid, then the it would cost $3 for 3 TAP cards (I'm travelling with two others) and 1.75*3=$5.25 for 3 one-way trips, totaling to $8.25. Is this calculation correct? It seems that this would be cheaper than 3 tickets from the airport to Union Station (3x9.75=$29.25).

Also, the Metro rail's site says that a one way TAP card use "Includes transfers to other Metro lines for up to two hours to complete a one-way trip." By "2hrs" are they referring to the transfer time between any two stops or are they referring to the total time of the journey (including stops)?

EDIT: my question isn't a duplicate another existing question because that question does not have the metro route combination I'm referring to. Also, I'm travelling with three people, each of whom will have a luggage. My luggage in particular will have to be checked, unlike the one in the already-existing question.

EDIT 2: the route whose link I've given in the question is this: Take the free Green Line shuttle to Aviation/LAX stop, then remain on the green line to travel to Willowbrook station, transfer onto the blue line and travel to 7th center/Metro station in downtown. This route is not the same as that of another existing question. I figured from the calculation above it would be cheaper to take this metro route than it would to take the FlyAway Bus. Secondly, the FlyAway bus may be a little more susceptible (although less so compared to taxicabs) to congestion at around the time I'll be leaving LAX (approx. 5:40pm).

Comment: @choster My question refers to a specific bus route, which is not included in the question you suspect mine is a duplicate of.

Comment: You didn't specify a route, and the top route on the other site is precisely the preferred method indicated in the earlier question here: the FlyAway bus to Union Station. This is the least hassle, regardless of whether or not you have bags. Please [edit] your post if there is any reason why you do not want to take the FlyAway bus, but also note that there is no advantage to taking the Silver over the Blue. Also note that MetroLink is a completely separate service run by a different agency from Metro Rail and Metro Bus.

Comment: Where exactly downtown are you trying to go?

Comment: @ZachLipton I've booked a place on West 7th street, so the metro to 7th st./Metro center is a good option, as my lodging is only some minutes walk from there